# Read a file in ruby

Tags: ruby, file

I'm trying to create a function that reads a file and returns the content of the file. I've tried the next option, but it doesn't run:

```rb
def read (text) 
    File.foreach(text) do |line| 
        puts line 
    end 
end
```

This is the error:

```
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - my/file/path
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please, edit your question. You need to be more specific when you ask for help on a problem. Provide the exact error encountered in console or eventually in your idle.

Comment: You need to replace **my/file/path** with the path in which there is the current file that you want to open.

Answer (score 1):

For read a text file with Ruby you should try something like:

```
File.open("my/file/path", "r") do |f| #change it with your current path
  f.each_line do |line|
    puts line
  end
end
# File is closed automatically at end of block
```

By the way, there are several ways for perform what you're trying to reach. Also very short solutions like puts `File.read(your_file_name)` or you can process it by-line in a very strictly form like:

```
File.foreach( 'your_file.txt' ) do |line| #line-by-line
  puts line
end
```